# ASP.NET Identity : Cannot sign-in existed user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I use `ASP.NET Identity 2` in an `MVC 5` project and there are some users in `AspNetUsers` table. Although these users have been created and validated, it is impossible to retrieve any of them bu using:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
```

Please note that I used email addressed for `UserName` as `Email` fields and it is ok to use email address for retrieving users.

On the other hand, I can retrieve the users by:

```
ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email == model.Email);
```

But, I cannot make sign-in the user with the following code and the result is always **Failure**.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Email, 
    model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: Does anybody else have no idea?

Comment: Can you post your registration code? Also can you verify that in your DB the UserName and Email are identical?

Comment: I see that the problem is related to security stamp. For example I created a user and then this user can login without no problem. However, when changing email or username of this user, the new user cannot login. It is good for security, but I have no idea how the mechanism works. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You are describing a different problem now. If you don't change the UserName, doe's the `PasswordSignInAsync` work?

Comment: Actually I populated the tables by using EF Code First and then transfer data from old database to the newly populated database tables. The problem occurs on the newly populated tables and I think the reason is security stamp. Because all the column values on the same table are the same. Is that true that security stamp causes this problem? And what should I do in order to transfer data between AspNetUsers tables?